# NextJS dynamic urls query not passing back ID

Tags: next.js

I am trying to load data when clicking on a `<Link>` by passing an ID as a query param. I also need to have a clean URL so I set the "as" option. My problem is that the query param I get back on the loading page is now the value I passed in "as" so I can't use the ID to fetch my data.

Is there an alternative way or something I'm missing?

What I need query param to be is => id = 3

What I'm getting is the slug name => id = "Uncategorized"

`<Link key={i} href={{pathname: '/blog/category/[id]', query: {id: cat.category_id}}} as={`/blog/category/${cat.category_slug}`}>
      <a>{cat.category_name}</a>
     </Link>`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by fetching all my categories before fetching my posts and matching the category slug with the query.id. I don't know if there is a more nextjs way of doing this but it works for now.